# Unable to install Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, database

error message as below appeared after database details is entered this is an excerpt as the original is too long.

It is a fresh install without any sample data imported into the database. Tried many times but it won't get past this page. What could be wrong?

```
Zend_Db_Statement_Exception Object
(
    [_previous:Zend_Exception:private] => 
    [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`19`.`cms_block_store`, CONSTRAINT `cms_block_store_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `cms_block_store` (`block_id`,`store_id`) VALUES (?, ?)
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 23000
    [file:protected] => /var/www/._./19/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
    [line:protected] => 235
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/._./19/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php
                    [line] => 110
                    [function] => _execute
                    [class] => Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 97
                                    [1] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following points.

1. Check if innodb is installed/not disabled if you are using red hat.
2. Run the magento check file on your server to check if everything is working fine. http://www.magentocommerce.com/_media/magento-check.zip
3. If you are using sample data check install magento after importing sample data.

Please let me know if you are still having any issues.

Comment: 1. innodb is running with blue color.
2. Magento check is running fine
3. Its an empty db without sample data

and the status is still the same